# How to get underlined title report by converting sxw to rml format using base_report_designer module?

Tags: python, reportlab, odoo

**Problem:**
I have sxw file and whenever I convert it in rml file using base_report_designer module(OpenERP module), and generate report I do not get underlined fonts in report which are underlined in sxw though but not in rml file.I changed font format & size then after I did not get underlined fonts in report.Currently in sxw font type is "Liberation Serif" and font size is "12".
I tried most of font types but did not get undelined fonts in report.
Currntly I solve this problem by adding "bold" tag in rml file. And the problem of this solution is, whenever I convert sxw to rml, I've to add "bold" tag everytime.

**Suggest Solution:**
Kindly give me another solution of this problem so that whenever I convert sxw to rml, I get underlined fonts in report without explicitly adding "underline" tag in RML.

Comment: Pls put a link to both the files so that we can recreate the problem and solve it for u.

Answer (score 0):

For better report customisation, use Aeroo Reports from Alistek. With this module, you can use your odt file without changing anything...

Comment: Yes, Here is the description :(http://www.alistek.com/index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=93%3Aaeroo-reports-for-open-erp-5-a-6&catid=34%3Azias)